# identifier "in" is undefined

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have this Shader.h file I'm making with this code in it:

```
#include <GL\GL.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>

in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec3 textColor;

void main() {
    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoords).r);
    color = vec4(textColor, 1.0) * sampled;
}
```

The problem is im getting a error from `in vec2 TexCoords;` saying that "in" is undefined. I am not sure if this is in a library or not and how to properly use it in this header file. I am follwoing a tutorial to draw text from the learnOpengl website: https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering

Can anyone tell what headers/libraries I need to include to get this working or what I have done wrong

Comment: Asking for libraries is unfortunately off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `in` is part of GLSL, not C++. You should not have `#include` lines in a glsl file and you should not use a C++ compiler to compile it

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems here.

1. You are mixing C++ and GLSL
2. You are missing the line that defines the version of GLSL you are using. (The first versions of GLSL didn't support the 'in' keyword).
3. texture() isn't a GLSL command, you're probably looking for texture2D?

Your shader should look like:

```cpp
// Use GLSL 4.5
#version 450

in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec3 textColor;

void main() {
    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture2D(text, TexCoords).r);
    color = vec4(textColor, 1.0) * sampled;
}
```

Separately you'll need to write the C++ code to define the geometry, specify the buffers, and compile the shaders.

Comment: how would I define the version of GLSL that Im using

Comment: It's specified in my code example. In this case, version 4.5

Comment: When I do #version 450 I get the error unrecognised preprocesing directive

Comment: This still sounds like you are mixing C++ and GLSL? Have to passed the shader (as a text string!) to glShaderSource?

Comment: @robthebloke for your point 3. texture() is certainly a glsl command, texture2D() is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the headers that are the problem. That code that you have there is written in the OpenGL programming language (glsl). So in order to pass them to your shader program. That particular part of code should be passed to your Shader.h file via string. You want to put the code for your fragment shader and vertex shader in 2 separate files and pass that to the shader program via string. Then you can read the code from the files directly into your shader.  Something like this:

```
ShadingProgram::ShadingProgram(std::string vp, std::string fp)
{
    std::string shader;
    GLuint shader_id;
    const GLchar *source;

    _program = glCreateProgram();

    shader = GetShaderCode(vp);
    shader_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    source = shader.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader_id, 1, &source, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader_id);
    CheckCompilation(shader_id, vp);
    glAttachShader(_program, shader_id);

    shader = GetShaderCode(fp);
    shader_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    source = shader.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader_id, 1, &source, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader_id);
    CheckCompilation(shader_id, fp);
    glAttachShader(_program, shader_id);
    glLinkProgram(_program);
    CheckLinking();
}
```

Notice how in the learnopengl tutorial they have multiple files and the full source code for you to look at.

Alternatively, use this example to write the glsl code as a string directly into your program.

https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/2.2.hello_triangle_indexed/hello_triangle_indexed.cpp

Comment: How do I create the shader program

Comment: You can impliment it as a class, or you can just use opengl's shader functions directly from main. I suggest just copying what they have in learnopengls source code if you don't understand everything, because the prerequisite knowledge for implimenting shaders is very high.